# Taking an array from a .csv file and inserting into a postgresql DB fails from a BASH script. Adding extran "," to the psql command

Tags: arrays, postgresql, bash

I'm trying to take the contents of a .csv file and INSERT it into a postgresql table, but I get syntax errors when running the script as it looks like it's adding a , where there shouldn't be one.

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ...1", "2023-12-10 04:59:41", "2023-12-10 05:00:48", , "-", , "... ^` 
The data from this line in the .csv file is as follows.

1,"+18654752227","+18653509420","+12009990871","2023-12-10 04:59:41","2023-12-10 04:59:41","2023-12-10 05:00:48","-","-","16 No error","?","INT","Local","no indication","true",""

Here is the code of the bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
export DBHost="######"
export DBPort="####"
export DBUser="#######"
export DBName="######"
export PGPASSWORD='#######'
export DBTable="######"
export File=$1 

while read -r line
do
        IFS=',' read -ra values <<< "$line"
        Seq_NO="${values[0]}"
        Charge_Number="${values[1]}"
        Calling_Number="${values[2]}"
        Called_Number="${values[3]}"
        Seize_Time="${values[4]}"
        Answer_Time="${values[5]}"
        Release_Time="${values[6]}"
        Inbound_Trunk="${vales[7]}"
        Outbound_Trunk="${values[8]}"
        Release="${values[9]}"
        Redirect="${values[10]}"
        Topology="${values[11]}"
        Type="${values[12]}"
        Privacy="${values[13]}"
        Answered="${values[14]}"
        Carrier="${values[15]}"

        psql -h "$DBHost" -p "$DBPort" -U "$DBUser" -d "$DBName" -c "INSERT INTO CDR (Seq_NO, Charge_Number, Calling_Number, Called_Number, Seize_Time, Answer_Time, Release_Time, Inbound_Trunk, Outbound_Trunk, Rlease, Redirect, Topology, Type, Privacy, Answered, Carrier) VALUES ($Seq_NO, $Charge_Number, $Calling_Number, $Called_Number, $Seize_Time, $Answer_Time, $Release_Time, $Inbound_Trunk, $Outbound_Trunk, $Rlease, $Redirect, $Topology, $Type, $Privacy, $Answered, $Carrier)"
done < $1
```

I tried setting the default of each array value to "NULL" thinking it was because of unset data, but that didn't make a difference.

I'm at a loss.

Comment: You have a typo in `Inbound_Trunk="${vales[7]}"`. And `$Rlease` in the psql part.

Comment: This isn't the source of the problem, but why do you bother with the `line` variable? It looks like you could skip it, and redi directly into the `values` array with `while IFS=',' read -ra values; do`

Comment: Depending on the CSV, you could use copy or \copy (in psql) instead of INSERT to make your script much faster.

Comment: The `$Rlease` typo would have been immediately spotted if you used `set -u`.